# run call_user_func_array() with timeout

Tags: php

Is there a way to run a function using `call_user_func_array()` with a timeout?
So if it runs for over a minute, it stops?

I am runing a function and saving it´s return value like this.

```
$result = call_user_func_array($function,array(0));
```

I would like this function to stop running if it takes longer than 60 seconds...

Comment: Not without forking the process, unless you want to timeout the entire script.  PHP is synchronous.

Comment: @Devon It's worth mentioning that you can only fork processes in PHP if you are on a *nix system.

Comment: Thanks both of you! That really cleared things up! :)